# PL/SQL escape character like for statement

Tags: plsql, escaping, special-characters

I've tried to search but didn't found an answer.

I've created with PL/SQL, HTML, CSS and Javascript a web application.

People can search for article and write a comment to These articles.
If they click the submit button it starts to search with the conditions of the customer.

I send the conditions as param and store them into variables.

After that I start my Statement and refresh the page with the new records.
If someone writes a comment with Special characters like

> (&, %, ", ', _)

my page crashes because the Statement string isn't correct anymore.

The Statement Looks like

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE Name LIKE ('''%'||nameVar||'%''');
```

Excuse my english
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first your question about "ESCAPING" lead me to the wrong way, because you can define a "ESCAPE" character for a like Statement: This would take your % or _ in your Statement literal:

```
where ..... like '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

should find a record with an % in the column.

**BUT THATS NOT YOUR PROBLEM!**

Your web application has to HTML encode your string - then you can store it in any database.

This has to be done by your frontend (whatever it is: ASP.NET, PHP, etc ...)

After a short Google search I found this: HTF Package, the HTF.ESCAPE_SC function encodes the string to be useable in SQL Statements.

Maybe this link helps you: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b15896/pshtp.htm